# How to do an F-test in VBA

Tags: vba, statistics

Does anyone know how I do an F-test in VBA. I'm looking to compare two columns comparing values on consecutive days. I need to hypothesis test and flag if it fails at p > .05. Any advice welcome.
Thanks

Comment: http://codevba.com/excel/WorksheetFunction/FTest.htm

Comment: Thanks Tim that's just what I needed.